# Apply soft edges to image using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, gradient, opacity

Given an image, is there a way to soften the edges using css? Or through some js library (although css would be preferred)? The idea is that the edges of the image should blur into transparency, so they fit in better with the background.

Example, original image:

[image: Original image]

Image with softened edges:
[image: Image with soft edges]

There are many similar questions asked on stackoverflow, however none (that I can find) offer an answer to do exactly this. Mostly they're concerned with blurring the whole image, or setting a semi-transparent border on the image, neither being what I'm looking for.

Comment: why don't you edit the image in photoshop/gimp to look like that and place the img inside a div container?

Comment: Because the images will be user uploaded and the effect should be applied at runtime.

Comment: I'd just like to state that I did not set the title to this question. The original question was "apply soft edges to image using css", because "soft edges" is the name by which I know this effect (it's what this is called in MS Word, which I used to generate the example). I imagine it is the name other people know it as, as well, who will now again have a harder time finding the below answers. Seems a shame. Also, the typo in the title "Applz" is an unlucky finger twitch of the editor. @DJDavid98: why did you feel it necessary to edit my question, which seemed perfectly to the point?

Comment: Feather is used in most of the advanced image editing programs, like Photoshop, if I remember correctly. If you disagree, feel free to change it back. Also, sorry for the typo, I corrected it now.

Comment: I disagree in that sense that there is indeed more information available once you know the keyword "feather", but this is only useful once you know that keyword. For non-image editors, a "soft edge" is a much more intuitive term - also what is used in MS Word - where we will start our search from.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try something like this:

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Konrud/owcdfjuh/)

HTML :

```
<div id="image-container"><div>
```

CSS:

```
#image-container {
background: url(http://pic2.ooopic.com/11/26/30/31b1OOOPIC48.jpg) left top no-repeat;
box-shadow: 25px 25px 50px 0 white inset, -25px -25px 50px 0 white inset; 
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This only give the illusion of a feathered edge. This fails if the background is not a solid color

Answer (score 4):

You can try that: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2m68ykL/30/)

```
<div class="shadow">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/" />
</div>
```

And CSS.

```
shadow
{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.shadow:before
{
    display:block;
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 6px 6px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 6px 6px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 6px 6px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use box shadow, it comes with a weird graphics error and your image doesnt really go over to transparent. Use masking. great article below.

https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/#aa-masking

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="170" height="200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask">
      <ellipse cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="25%" ry="25%" fill="white" filter="url(#filter)"></ellipse>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" width="170" height="200" mask="url(#mask)"></image>
</svg>
```